# Sorting Drupal view by date but place expired items at the bottom?

Tags: drupal-7, view

I have a view that lists items that have "expiry" dates. For example:

```
Item 1: Expired yesterday [EXPIRED]
Item 2: Expires in an hour [NOT EXPIRED]
Item 3: Expires in 5 hours [NOT EXPIRED]
```

If I order by data asc, I get this order. The problem is, I want:

```
Item 2: Expires in an hour [NOT EXPIRED]
Item 3: Expires in 5 hours [NOT EXPIRED]
Item 1: Expired yesterday [EXPIRED]
```

So that all expired items fall to the bottom.

I would imagine I need to somehow create another field that indicates "expired" and then sort by that too, but I don't know how to sort by a "generated" field, if you know what I mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the [Drupal Computed Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field). I added this to my product and then simply sorted by it on the views.